# Spring Boot + React + Docker app returning 404 Not Found

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, nginx, docker-compose

I have a Spring and React app that I am deploying using docker compose and nginx.

I am having trouble with the configuration of the frontend. The backend is receiving requests ok.

However, when I send a request to the frontend on my local machine using the URL e.g. http://localhost:5173/about, I receive a  404 Not Found in Postman and browser.

My docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql-db-container
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"

  internet-speed-backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: server/Dockerfile
    container_name: backend-service-container
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb

  react-ui:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: client/Dockerfile
    container_name: react-service-container
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5173:80"
    depends_on:
    - internet-speed-backend
```

My nginx configuation for the frontend

```
events {}

http {
  upstream backend {
    server internet-speed-backend:8080;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;  
    }
    
    location @backend {
      proxy_pass http://backend$request_uri;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
  }
}
```

My dockerfile for the frontend and nginx:

```
#### Stage 1: Build the angular application
FROM node as build

# the /app directory should act as main application directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy the package.json as well as the package-lock.json 
COPY client/package.json client/package-lock.json ./

# Install the node depenadencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the main application
COPY client/ ./

# Build the application
RUN npm run build

#### Stage 2: serve the react application from Nginx for production environment
FROM nginx

# Copy the react build from Stage 1
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
# Copy custom nginx config
COPY client/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Expose port 80 to the Docker host, so accessible from outside
EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx","-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: Does it work if you try this without nginx?

Comment: No it didn't work when I tried without nginx

Comment: Can you check the `depends_on` in `react-ui` docker compose file? Looks incorrect.

Comment: sorry - that was a typo here it was fine in the file. I am still getting the same error

Comment: Possible to update the question by removing the nginx portions (since thats not relevant) and will be easier to debug?